# How to get Component object in Component Presentation storage extension

Tags: java, tridion, tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery, tridion-storage-extension

I am trying to write storage extension in Tridion 2011 where I will extend `JPAComponentPresentationDAO` and implement `ComponentPresentationDAO`.

```
public void create(ComponentPresentation itemToCreate, ComponentPresentationTypeEnum componentPresentationType) throws StorageException 
{
    super.create(itemToCreate,componentPresentationType);   
    String tcmURI = Integer.toString(itemToCreate.getComponentId());
    Component compObject // I want Component object to get the schema ID 
    PublishActionDAO publishActionDAO = (PublishActionDAO) StorageManagerFactory.getDefaultDAO("PublishAction");
    PublishAction publishAction = new PublishAction();
    publishAction.setAction("ADD"); 
    publishAction.setTcmUri(tcmURI);
    publishActionDAO.store(publishAction);
}
```

In above sample code I want to make Component object using`itemToCreate.getComponentId()` where I get the component ID, so that I can pass some useful detail to my entity class which will store that data in my database table.

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you're asking. Do you simply want to know how to get the DAO for `Component`s from within this code?

Comment: Yes, actullay I want to handle component publish and unpublish, so that I am trying to get Component object here so that I can get schema id of published or unpublished component

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will be able to get the Schema Id from `ComponentMeta` which is inherited from ItemMeta. First you need to get the `ItemDAO` from the `StorageManagerFactory` and then `findByPrimaryKey` will give to ComponentMeta. This only works after your `super.create` which should persist the component to broker db. Try this out.

**Sample snippet :**

```java
ItemDAO item = (ItemDAO) StorageManagerFactory.getDAO(pubid,StorageTypeMapping.COMPONENT_META);
ComponentMeta meta = (ComponentMeta) item.findByPrimaryKey(pubid,compid);
int schemaID = meta.getSchemaId() ;
```

Note: you need to pass the pubid, compid from you itemToCreate tcmURI

Comment: @Ram...thanks as I am trying to extend JPAComponentPresentationDAO so can adding/deleting/updating of component could be managed on extending this or do I need to extend some other class